# Wild card characters replacement in string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, wildcard

Im having trouble getting wildString to go into the wildSum array. this is what I need to run with this program.

Sample Run 1:

```
Enter the first String:
D*g
Enter the replacement String:
in
Output: Ding
```

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the first string:");
    String wildString = input.nextLine(); 
    char [] wildStringArray = wildString.toCharArray();

    System.out.println("Enter the replacement String:");
    String replaceString = input.nextLine(); 


    if(wildString.contains("*") != true) {
        System.out.println("Error: no *");
    }

    if (wildString.contains("\t") == true && wildString.contains(" ") == true && wildString.toLowerCase() != wildString.toUpperCase()) {
        System.out.println("Error: Incorrect characters");

    }
    char [] wildSum = new char[wildString.length() + replaceString.length() -1];
    char wildSum[] = new char[wildString.toCharArray()];

    for (int i = 0; i < wildSum.length; i ++ )
    {
    // insert wildString into wildSum
        if( wildSum[i] == '*' ) {   

            /* for (int i=0; i < wildSum.length(); i++) {
                  wildSum[i] = wildSum[i].replace('*', replaceString);
                }   */
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an exception? if so show the stack trace. Wrong output? Tell us what you get and what you expected instead.

Comment: This is not the whole code. It got truncated in the middle. Please complete it. And also add the nature of your problem. One note, though: don't compare strings with `==`.  Your condition for "Incorrect characters" is completely wrong.

Comment: Yes it is suppose to test the input to make sure that it contains one * and that there are no spaces, or "\t" and that all the characters are from the alphabet @RealSkeptic

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the first string:");
    String wildString = input.nextLine(); 


    System.out.println("Enter the replacement String:");
    String replaceString = input.nextLine(); 

    System.out.println(wildString.replaceAll("\\*",replaceString));
```

Comment: This could be problematic with strings containing multiple `*` but we don't know how that is intended to be handled.

Comment: ok.. can you give exmaple of any String , I just tried with 1**2*3 . It seems to work. you can try the code [here](http://runnable.com/me/VWXhK3diOm0IfxsN)

Comment: Again, we don't know how it is meant to be handled. There are two options I see here: First, multiple wildcards mean multiple inserts `D**g -> Dining`. This is what your code currently does. Second multiple wildcards are disregarded `D**g -> Ding`. It's a matter of which logic is desired here, and without knowing that, we can't be sure what is correct.

Comment: yes, I agree. It totally depends on requirement. My code was purely to address wildcard replacement problem he was facing. With this problem solved, coder can write his own logic to replace them as needed. replaceAll was just one example

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I believe that the program is only intended for one * so  i will try that. Is there a way to do it with array?